# The import javax.ws cannot be resolved on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, tomcat

I am developing a **RESTful's Webservice on java using Eclipse** with the next steps:

> File>New>Dynamic Web Project

Then I configured these options:

> Target runtime: Apache Tomcat v7.0;
>
> Dynamic web module version: 2.5 (because  I am using Axis2);
>
> Configuration: Default Configuration for Apache Tomcat v7.0 and  (both options)

In label "Modify" I added "Axis2 Web Services" and "JAX-RS (REST Web Services)"

Next, when I created my new class, I added

> import javax.ws.rs.GET;
> import javax.ws.rs.Path;
> import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
> import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
> import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

but Eclipse launches the notice

> The import javax.ws cannot be resolved

I don't know **the next question**

- Is it necessary to add all the files .jar to the path WebContent/WEB-INF/lib ?
- Or you can create, for example, a new path WebContent/WEB-INF/lib-RESTproyect?
- If I choose the second option, will I have a problem in the future with my project?

Comment: Yes it is necessary to add all thrid party jar on classpath because when deployed on server all library will automatically sync on server.

Comment: Add an implementation of JAX-RS specs, eg jersey etc... jars

Comment: @Darshan you have reason, but do you know if I would use another path, or I have to use "WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" by default? Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Import the jar file: javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
And add it to java build path. The issue will be resolved in windows.

Answer (score 17):

Import the jar file: javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar And add it to java build path. The issue will be resolved in windows.

Link to the jar : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxwsrsapi20jar.htm

Information on importing it to Eclipse : http://tech.amikelive.com/node-269/eclipse-quick-tip-resolving-error-the-import-javaxservlet-cannot-be-resolved/comment-page-1/